# Unable to change checkout placeholder text

Tags: custom-field

I am using woocommerce with storefront and on the checkout the placeholder text for address 1 is "street name" and address 2 is "apartment number".

In my country it should be the opposite, or all in one field.

I have tried changing this with code snippets I found online. They change the placeholder but only for a split second while the page is loading. After that they change back to the default values

- https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326620/custom-placeholder-for-all-woocommerce-checkout-fields

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' 'override_billing_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );

   function override_billing_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
       $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['placeholder'] = 'Address line 1';
       $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['placeholder'] = 'Address line 2';

       $fields['Shipping']['shipping_address_1']['placeholder'] = 'Address line 1';
       $fields['Shipping']['shipping_address_2']['placeholder'] = 'Address line 2'; 
       return $fields;
       }


   add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'uwc_new_address_one_placeholder', 1 );

   function uwc_new_address_one_placeholder( $fields ) {
       $address_fields['address_1']['placeholder'] = 'Address line 1';
       $address_fields['address_2']['placeholder'] = 'Address line 2';
       return $address_fields;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the default fields, but there was a small mistake in my code. The correct code was:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'uwc_new_address_one_placeholder', 1 );

   function uwc_new_address_one_placeholder( $address_fields) {
       $address_fields['address_1']['placeholder'] = 'Address line 1';
       $address_fields['address_2']['placeholder'] = 'Address line 2';
       return $address_fields;
       }
```

Notice the change to `$address_fields` on line 3

Comment: For anyone looking to customise their WooCommerce checkout fields, I have written a simple tutorial on this here:

https://wpharvest.com/override-woocommerce-checkout-fields/